# Django - Team/User relationships

Tags: python, django

I'm at a loss... I'm just learning Django and I am really rather confused about how to make a field work the way I would like it to.

I understand that Django has a native "Groups" model.  However, I am looking to build my own teams model for customization and practice.

Here is my models.py file for my Users app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Team(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.BooleanField("Admin Status")
```

Here's where I'm confused.  I would like to be able to call the team that the user is part of directly from User.Profile.  So, I want to add a field to my Profile class that will automatically populate with the team name when a user is added to a team.

A potential problem I can see is that, currently, I can assign a user to multiple teams.  This doesn't bother me, perhaps I can have a Profile model field that automatically populates with a list of all the teams that the user is associated with.  Regardless, I can't figure out what type of field I would need to use, or how to do this.

Does that make sense?

Comment: With the current implementation a `Profile` can belong to *multiple* teams, so "*I would like to be able to call the team that the user is part of directly from User.Profile*" does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

> A potential problem I can see is that, currently, I can assign a user to multiple teams.

Indeed, you can however easily retrieve the `Team`s the *`myprofile`* object is a member of with:

```
Team.objects.filter(members__profile=myprofile)
```

You thus can make a property for the `Profile` model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.BooleanField("Admin Status")
    
    @property
    def teams(self):
        return Team.objects.filter(
            members__profile=self
        )
```

Then you thus access the `Team`s of a `myprofile` with `myprofile.teams`.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I want to add a field to my Profile class that will automatically populate with the team name when a user is added to a team.

From my limited knowledge of database, you can add a name field to your `Team` model.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind your requirement as mentioned in question, i would suggest you to use django reverse relations to get all the teams the profile is associated with

```
user_teams = User.objects.get(id='user_id').profile_set.all()[0].team_set.all()
```

to know more about django ORM reverse relation, here is a very short [article](https://paulgrajewski.medium.com/django-reverse-relationship-e6b1939561e2)